# How can I make a checkbox readonly? not disabled?

Tags: javascript, checkbox

I have a form where I have to post form values to my action class. In this form I have a checkbox that needs to be readonly. I tried setting `disabled="true"` but that doesn't work when posting to the action class.

So please advice??

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly

Comment: this is not working for me....thats the problem..I am using <s:iterator> and retrieving status value in action class... here is the code for that                                             <c:choose>
  <c:when test="#divisionCdSid.first == true">
  <s:iterator value="divisionList" status="divisionCdSid" id="entity">
 <input type="checkbox" name="divisionCdSid" id="exportDivision" value="<s:property value="sid"/>" checked onclick="return false" onkeydown="return false"/>
 <s:property value="divsionNm" />
 </s:iterator> 
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>

Comment: could you please edit the original question and put the code there in code format (tabbed out 4 spaces)  its unreadable in the comment.  Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can HTML checkboxes be set to readonly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/155291/can-html-checkboxes-be-set-to-readonly)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can easily do this by css.
**HTML :**

```
<form id="aform" name="aform" method="POST">
    <input name="chkBox_1" type="checkbox" checked value="1" readonly />
    <br/>
    <input name="chkBox_2" type="checkbox" value="1" readonly />
    <br/>
    <input id="submitBttn" type="button" value="Submit">
</form>
```

**CSS :**

```
input[type="checkbox"][readonly] {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/s45tex41/)

Comment: This doesn't prevent ticking of the checkbox via the keyboard (tab to the checkbox, and hit spacebar).

Comment: For preventing ticking of the checkbox via the keyboard, please use Patrick's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/12267350/1091926

Comment: If the checkbox is followed by a label (which is also clickable), we may also add this CSS: input[type="checkbox"][readonly] + label { pointer-events: none; }

Comment: @jtheletter, just need to add `tab-index="-1"`

Comment: The best solution of century

Comment: does not prevent the box from being clicked on with the mouse in chrome and the field read by php as clicked or unclicked.  Functionally it does nothing to change the behavior of the field.

Answer (score 132):

There is no property to make the checkbox readonly. But you can try this trick.

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false" />
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/wfVFW/3/)**

Comment: I tried but not working..When I click on the checkbox its getting unchecked

Comment: @Naga, You can see the demo its working correctly. I have added the demo in my answer.

Comment: @Naga Agree with Kundan. Even checked it in most browsers to ensure that I'm not missing something.

Comment: Nice trick so that I don't need to create some dummmmmmy field together with hidden field.

Comment: Works with keyboard navigation, too (tab to it, hit spacebar).

Comment: Excellent answer.

Answer (score 43):

```
<input type="checkbox" checked onclick="return false;" onkeydown="return false;"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2srjc/

If you are worried about tab order, only return false for the keydown event when the tab key was not pressed:

```
<input type="checkbox" checked onclick="return false;" onkeydown="e = e || window.event; if(e.keyCode !== 9) return false;"/>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2srjc/149/

Comment: Thanks.. It worked now..Its because of the if case that caused problem.. Thanks

Comment: This stops you being able to tab through the elements @MRodrigues answer is a better solution

Comment: For readonly, your supposed to be able to tab through the checkboxes but not be able to change the value with the space bar.   Neither of these solutions does that.

Comment: On Mac/Safari, the checkbox can still trigger a "change" event in jQuery if the checkbox itself is clicked. To prevent triggering such jQuery event, please also implement AleX's answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/41486636/1091926

Comment: Along with the above correct answer , if you want to set the css as for it to show it as disabled use following jsfiddle example

https://jsfiddle.net/founddrama/eKSuj/

Answer (score 16):

I personally like to do it this way:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="option" value="1" disabled="disabled" />
<input type="hidden" name="option" value="1">
```

I think this is better for two reasons:

1. User clearly understand that he can't edit this value
2. The value is sent when submitting the form.

Answer (score 10):

You may simply add `onclick="return false"` - this will stop browser executing default action (checkbox checked/not checked will not be changed)

Comment: this is not working for me....thats the problem..I am using <s:iterator> and retrieving status value in action class... here is the code for that                                             <c:choose>
  <c:when test="#divisionCdSid.first == true">
  <s:iterator value="divisionList" status="divisionCdSid" id="entity">
 <input type="checkbox" name="divisionCdSid" id="exportDivision" value="<s:property value="sid"/>" checked onclick="checkStatusSid();" onkeydown="return false"/>
 <s:property value="divsionNm" />
 </s:iterator> 
  </c:when>
  <c:otherwise>

Comment: @Naga - nothing stops you from onclick="checkStatusSid(); return false;"  But if onkeydown="return false;" works for you - than why not?

Answer (score 6):

Make a fake checkbox with no name and value, force the value in an hidden field:

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" checked="checked">
<input type="hidden" name="name" value="true">
```

Note: if you put name and value in the checkbox, it will be anyway overwritten by the input with the same name

Comment: This answer is better than the accepted answer because it prevents changing the checkbox using the keyboard.   One slight improvement would be to use CSS to prevent the gray color that comes with disabling a checkbox.  It should stay black.

Answer (score 3):

I use JQuery so I can use the readonly attribute on checkboxes.

```
//This will make all read-only check boxes truly read-only
$('input[type="checkbox"][readonly]').on("click.readonly", function(event){event.preventDefault();}).css("opacity", "0.5");
```

If you want the checkbox to be editable again then you need to do the following for the specific checkbox.

```
$('specific checkbox').off('.readonly').removeAttr("readonly").css("opacity", "1")
```

Comment: This solved my problem nicely, although I did it on document because I'm dynamically loading in elements on the page and I don't have to unbind the event when I remove the attribute: 

$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"][readonly]', function (event) { event.preventDefault(); });

I also added a style rather than adding the opacity with JQuery

input[type='checkbox'][readonly]{
 opacity: 0.5;
}

Answer (score 3):

### If you say 'No' to the following:

1. `disable=true` because other functionalities may not work, such as form posting.
2. `onclick='return false'` because other events may still trigger the
   change, such as keyup, keydown when on focus.
3. `e.preventDefault()`
4. CSS: `pointer-events: none;` because you may want to allow change
   under certain conditions.

Then just do this in the `change` event of your read-only checkbox:

```
$("#chkReadOnly").on("change", function () {
   // Enclose with 'if' statement if conditional.
   // Simply restore back the default value, i.e. true.
   $(this).prop("checked", true);
});
```

This will solve all the above problems.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, i only needed it within certain conditions, and to be done easily in HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" [style.pointer-events]="(condition == true) ? 'none' : 'auto'">
```

Or in case you need this consistently:

```
<input type="checkbox" style="pointer-events: none;">
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above worked for me. Here's my vanilla.js solution:

```
(function() {
    function handleSubmit(event) {
        var form = event.target;
        var nodes = form.querySelectorAll("input[disabled]");
        for (var node of nodes) {
            node.disabled = false;
        }
    }

    function init() {
        var submit_form_tag = document.getElementById('new_whatever');
        submit_form_tag.addEventListener('submit', handleSubmit, true);
    }

    window.onload = init_beworst;

})();
```

Be sure to provide an appropriate replacement for the form id.

My application has a bit of context, where some boxes are pre-checked, and others you have a limit of how many of the other boxes you can check. When you hit that limit, all the non-pre-checked boxes are disabled, and if you uncheck one all the non-pre-checked boxes are enabled again. When the user presses submit all the checked boxes are submitted to the user, regardless of whether they're pre-checked or not.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it directly, but you can do it with this way I try it, and it's work fine with me at the same time it is so simple

HTML :

`<input type="checkbox" checked  disabled="true" class="style" />`

CSS :

`.style{ opacity: 1; }`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (override) for Sencha ExtJS 7.2+ (checkbox and radio in a single override)

```
Ext.define('MyApp.override.field.Checkbox', {
    override: 'Ext.field.Checkbox',

    /**
     * OVERRIDE: to allow updateReadOnly to work propperly
     * @param {boolean} newValue
     *
     * To ensure the disabled state stays active if the field is still readOnly
     * we re - set the disabled state
     */
    updateDisabled(newValue) {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        if (!newValue && this.getReadOnly()) {
            this.inputElement.dom.disabled = true;
        }
    },

    /**
     * OVERRIDE: readonly for radiogroups and checkboxgroup do not work as other fields
     *     https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1953017/why-cant-radio-buttons-be-readonly
     *
     * @param {boolean} newValue
     *
     *  - use disabled on the field
     */
    updateReadOnly(value) {
        this.callParent(arguments);

        if (!this.getDisabled()) {
            this.inputElement.dom.disabled = value;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Extract from https://stackoverflow.com/a/71086058/18183749

> If you can't use the 'disabled' attribut (as it erases the value's
> input at POST), and noticed that html attribut 'readonly' works only
> on textarea and some input(text, password, search, as far I've seen),
> and finally, if you don't want to bother with duplicating all your
> select, **checkbox** and radio with hidden input, you might find the
> following function or any of his inner logics to your liking :

```
  addReadOnlyToFormElements = function (idElement) {

        // html readonly don't work on input of type checkbox and radio, neither on select. So, a safe trick is to disable the non-selected items
        $('#' + idElement + ' input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled',true); 

        // and, on the selected ones, to deactivate mouse/keyboard events and mimic readonly appearance
        $('#' + idElement + ' input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('tabindex','-1').css('pointer-events','none').css('opacity','0.5');
    }
```

And there's nothing easier than to remove these readonly

```
removeReadOnlyFromFormElements = function (idElement) {

     // Remove the disabled attribut on non-selected
    $('#' + idElement + ' input[type="checkbox"]:not(:checked)').prop('disabled',false); 
    
    // Restore mouse/keyboard events and remove readonly appearance on selected ones
    $('#' + idElement + ' input[type="checkbox"]:checked').prop('tabindex','').css('pointer-events','').css('opacity','');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Through CSS:

```
<label for="">
  <input type="checkbox" style="pointer-events: none; tabindex: -1;" checked> Label
</label>
```

*pointer-events not supported in IE<10*

https://jsfiddle.net/fl4sh/3r0v8pug/2/

Comment: That is what the accepted answer from back in January said. As pointed out in the comments, it doesn't prevent people from checking it with the keyboard.

Comment: @Quentin, it will if: 1. remove `label` tag; 2. add `tabindex` attribute - that's not a style.

Answer (score -4):

```
document.getElementById("your checkbox id").disabled=true;
```

Comment: `I tried setting disabled="true" but that doesn't work when posting to the action class.` - OP is looking for a solution that does not depend on the `disabled` attr