# Toggle readonly and disabled on checkboxes

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I'm using mvc, I need to change the "readonly" and "disabled" attributes of element `Html.CheckBoxFor`. I'm using a JavaScript for that:

```
function ReadOnlyHandle() {
            var Collection = document.getElementsByClassName("SubjectCB");
            debugger;
            for (var i = 0; i < Collection.length; i++)
            {
                Collection.item(i)..("disabled", "disabled");
                Collection.removeAttribute("readonly", "readonly");
            }

        debugger;
    }
```

I'm trying to get the collection of checkboxes (since I have few) and then iterate them to change their attributes.

```
@for (int i = 0; i < Model.Topics.Count(); i++)
                {
                    <tr id="row-@i">
                        <td>@Html.LabelFor(t => t.Topics[i].Box.Selected, Model.Topics[i].Box.Text)</td>
                        <td class="SubjectCB">@Html.CheckBoxFor(t => t.Topics[i].Box.Selected, new { @checked = "checked", @readonly = "readonly", @disabled = "disabled" })</td>
                        <td class="IsReadOnly">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topics[i].NumberOfNoDifficulltySet, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                        <td class="IsReadOnly">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topics[i].NumberOfEasy, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                        <td class="IsReadOnly">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topics[i].NumberOfMedium, new { @readonly = "readonly" })</td>
                        <td class="IsReadOnly">@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Topics[i].NumberOfHard, new { @readonly = "read" })</td>
                    </tr>
                }
```

Yet, in the collection, the variable defined in Javascript does not have the "removeAttribute" function - why is that? Or can I change the attributes another way?

Comment: i don't think you can call `removeAttribute` on the entire collection, try to do `Collection.item(i).removeAttribute`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, set the class on the actual checkbox instead of the `td` (or make another class for it):

```cs
<td>
      @Html.CheckBoxFor(t => t.Topics[i].Box.Selected, 
           new { 
                 @checked = "checked", 
                 @readonly = "readonly", 
                 @disabled = "disabled", 
                 @class = "SubjectCB" 
               }
      )
</td>
```

Next..
You're trying to remove an attribute from the entire collection. This should work better, using [disabled](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_option_disabled.asp) and [readOnly](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_text_readonly.asp):

```
Collection[i].disabled = false; //or true
Collection[i].readOnly = false; //or true
```

Or:

```
Collection[i].removeAttribute("readonly");
```

It should be noted though that `readOnly` **doesn't work** very well on checkboxes (if at all).

Instead, if you want to use something readonly-like, there is a work around posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12267242/how-can-i-make-a-checkbox-readonly-not-disabled):

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="return false;" />
```

*Edit: Apparently I forgot to remove .item from the code. Corrected now.*

Comment: Thank you for you help, however for some reason the use of Collection.item[i].removeAttribute("readonly") = false; creates an error: 0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'removeAttribute' of undefined or null reference - that is the function does not exists in this context... why? and the first solution: Collection.item[i].readOnly = false; //or true - does not change the attribute and it stays "readonly"... Do you have any isea about that? thanks again...

Comment: @LiorSmila I assume you got it working now? The code you posted in your comment is not the same as I posted in my answer. There should be no `.item` :) If this post contributed to the solution, please mark it as answer by clicking the check mark (top left of my answer)