# Disable entire form elements with respect to a state. React

Tags: javascript, html, forms, reactjs

I am disabling the inputs using the `isFetching` prop, 
but this is getting reduntant as I have to keep this in every input field.
Is there a way to disable the entire form?
Like a `disable` property in `<form>` tag or something?

```
<form>
  <input type="text" disabled={this.props.isFetching} />
  <input type="text" disabled={this.props.isFetching} />
</form>
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186342/3298693.

You should insert your a `<fieldset disabled="disabled">` inside your form encapsulating the set of disabled fields.

Comment: Shouldn't it instead be "You should insert a `<fieldset disabled="disabled">` element INSIDE your form"?

Answer (score 20):

I had the same issue and this worked for me:

```
 <fieldset disabled={true}>
```

Where true would be some "prop.setting"...

Comment: The best solution.

Answer (score -16):

Just use `<input type="text" disabled>` wherever you want the input text to be disabled. It hardly takes some time.

Comment: This is exactly what OP wants to avoid, as mentioned in the question.