# Convenient way to mark a complete form as readonly

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have an antd form with multiple form items and try to find a way to mark the complete form as readonly. I could for sure set each input component to 'disabled' but I wonder if there is a convenient way to do so on the form via an API call that I do not know yet.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping the antd form inside a fieldset and setting this to 'disabled' works pretty well.

```
<fieldset disabled={editorDisabled}>
  <Form>
    ...
  <Form/>
<fieldset/>
```

Comment: I saw this at https://stackoverflow.com/a/36216001 but I think it is only for html <form> not a antd form? Or rather I mean this didn't work for me in antd.

Comment: Not work with select, datepicker

Answer (score 1):

I don't see such an option in the [form api](https://ant.design/components/form/), and I think it's the rare use case, so I doubt it exists. However, you can simply add variable which will track the `disabled` status, i.e.:

```
const YourAwesomeComponent = (props) => {
     const disabled = someLogicToCalculateTheDisabledStatus(props);
     return <Form ...>
         <Input disabled={disabled} ... />
         <Select disabled={disabled} ... />
         <Button disabled={disabled} ... />
     </Form>
}
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

As of version [4.21.0](https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design/releases/tag/4.21.0) (Jun 6, 2022) the disabled prop can be used in the form to disable all fields, i.e.:

```
<Form disabled={true}>
...
</Form>
```

It is enforced as long as a `<Form.Item/>` isn't explicitly marked as not disabled with `disabled={false}`. You can see the reference in antd docs [here](https://ant.design/components/form#components-form-demo-disabled).