# How do I animate my form to fade in (or do other stuff) when I click a button using only vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

I'm trying to animate my Create Note form in when I click on a button but it just immediately comes in without a transition. What I'm trying to do is to add a class that sets its display from 'none' to 'flex'.

This is how the form looks (HTML)

```js
//Finally, this is the javascript that I'm trying to get it to work
const createBtn = document.getElementById('createBtn');
const form = document.getElementById('noteForm');

createBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  display: flex;
}

form {
  display: none;
  /* other propertites */
  transition: all 250ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<button id="createBtn">Create a Note</button>
<form id="noteForm">
  <!--form Content-->
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to be animating things in but I want to know how I can pull something like this off with vanilla JS.

Comment: Changing the display attribute will never result in a transition. What kind of transition are you hoping to implement?

Comment: try changing `visbility:hidden` to `visibility:visibile`

Comment: @robinsax yes you are right indeed. FZs just pointed that out. Thanks again :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to do fade-in and fade-out with JavaScript and CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6121203/how-to-do-fade-in-and-fade-out-with-javascript-and-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is right... except that `display` is not an animatable property.

For a fading effect, you have to use `opacity`:

```js
//Finally, this is the javascript that I'm trying to get it to work
const createBtn = document.getElementById('createBtn');
const form = document.getElementById('noteForm');

createBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.toggle('active');
});
```

```css
.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  /* other propertites */
  transition: all 250ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<button id="createBtn">Create a Note</button>
<form id="noteForm">
  <!--form Content-->
  <input type="text">
</form>
```

But note that the form will remain interactive even when hidden. To avoid that, you can use the solution from [this answer on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17186342/8376184):

```js
//Finally, this is the javascript that I'm trying to get it to work
const createBtn = document.getElementById('createBtn');
const form = document.getElementById('noteForm');
const fieldset = document.getElementById('noteFormFieldset');

createBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  form.classList.toggle('active');
  fieldset.disabled = !form.classList.contains('active')
});
```

```css
.active {
  opacity: 1;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  opacity: 0;
  /* other propertites */
  transition: all 250ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<button id="createBtn">Create a Note</button>
<form id="noteForm">
  <fieldset id="noteFormFieldset" disabled>
    <!--form Content-->
    <input type="text">
  </fieldset>
</form>
```

Comment: Ahhh! Thank you so much <3 I can't believe I wasted so much time just because I decided to animate one of the only few properties that are not transitionable :P