# How to disable a form conditionally in React

Tags: reactjs

I don't want to ask this simple question here but this feature is not working for me and I don't understand why. Everything looks correct:

```
class Questionnaire extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      status: true,
    };
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div disabled={this.state.status === true ? true : false}>
        <h1>The Form</h1>
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <input type="text" />
        <br />
        <button>Submit</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Questionnaire;
```

Do you see something wrong here? Please point out my mistake. Also I've created this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-bbt3y6?file=src%2FQuestionnaire.js).

Comment: You can't disable a div. You should use `fieldset` instead

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković, it's a very basic and simple form. Is there a workaround?

Comment: Yeah. Using a `fieldset`

Comment: I'm accepting answer from @Dmitriif. Also Roberto 's answer solved my problem. Both have valid points. Thank you all.

Comment: @RobertoZvjerković, yes, it answers my question. Thanks for the additional answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on what you want to achieve you can either set disabled on the entire form with a fieldset - [How can I make an entire HTML form "readonly"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3507958/how-can-i-make-an-entire-html-form-readonly)

or you can set `disabled` property to the submit button

Comment: Got it. I'm accepting this answer

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your div by `fieldset` instead.
or use below CSS

```
div[disabled=disabled] {
pointer-events: none;
opacity: 0.4;
}
```

check this: [How to disable all div content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/639815/how-to-disable-all-div-content)

Comment: Input elements with `pointer-events: none` can still be accessed using the keyboard